# ¿Cuál se debe usar, "quitar" o "sacar" para la ropa y los zapatos?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, verbos, ropa

¿Cuál se debe usar referente a la ropa y zapatos?

Por ejemplo, ¿sacarse los zapatos o quitarse los zapatos?

Answer (score 1):

Esto depende de donde seas. Si vives en un país americano, dirán sacarse la ropa, en España, en cambio, se dice quitarse la ropa, los zapatos, el sobrero, etc.

Comment: En Argentina los dos son correctos, sólo que "sacarse" es más común que "quitarse".

Comment: No del todo cierto. En Colombia usamos "quitarse".

Answer (score 0):

Ya es una pregunta de hace más de dos meses, pero para añadir a lo que respondió @Txortx, en general en España ambos verbos se pueden usar, pero con significados distintos: "Sacar" para "tender", y "quitar" para "desnudarse".

Comparemos ejemplos:

- "Quítate la ropa": "Desnúdate"
- "Voy a sacar la ropa [a tender]": "Voy a tender la ropa"

Espero que ayude.

Comment: "Sacar la ropa" es lo que dices pero "sacar**se** la ropa o los zapatos" es lo que muchos usan para "desnudarse".